# Growing Lilies In Greenhouse References

Tags: planting, greenhouse, lily

I'm looking for any kind of references (book , video , PDF , ...) for growing lilies in greenhouse. I heard Lilies are like a child and they need standard growing plan such as irrigation plan , ....

Comment: Lillys are very diverse, some like day Lillys aren't particular, others seem to be looking for a reason to kick off.

Comment: Just a tip, around here you'd do much better to ask for actual information instead of references to information. We're trying to be a good resource for people to find answers immediately instead of having to dig through a book.

Answer (score 3):

[This article](http://extension.umd.edu/publications/pdfs/fs687.pdf) goes into some detail on growing lilies for the specialty market. Here are the basics:

- essentially you are forcing the bulb to produce a flower.  This can be done year round but it is not economical to re-use bulbs. You plant new every crop.
- bulbs can be bought year round from growers in cool climates such as Oregon, Washington State and Chile and are shipped pre-chilled so they are ready to plant when they arrive.
- remove from packing, dry overnight
- use a soil less mix to ensure a well drained soil and plant in raised beds or crates with drip irrigation
- heating at night and supplemental lighting may be required depending on your location
- harvesting and post harvest handling depend on whether you are focused on the cut flower or live plant market.  Plants are sensitive to ethlyene so do not store with fruit.
- the most destructive pest is the [lily beetle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scarlet_lily_beetle) who is well known to home gardeners for the devastation that it causes on most lily species. Commercial growers prefer to grow under glass or poly with all vents and fans filtered with mesh to avoid the beetles entering the growing area.

If you are considering entering the commercial market to grow lilies remember that producing the product is only half the challenge.  You must have customers secured to buy your product before you plant.  A detailed explanation of floral industry practices is beyond the scope of this question due to it's regional nature.  However, chances are excellent that there is a commercial auction house in a major urban centre near you.  Contact them to find out what cultivars and quantities are in demand by buyers.